# История изменения данных в таблицах

Tags: sql, sql-server, база-данных

Есть некая таблица **А**, записи в которой постоянно правят, добавляют, удаляют. При чем, некторые поля изменяют чаще. Вопрос заключается в том как вести историю. У меня созрело два варианта:

1. Вести историю по всей таблице, т.е. создать копию таблицы **А**, например **А_History** и при каждом изменении в таблице **А** вносить запись в таблицу истории с указанием кто и когда это сделал.
2. Разделить поля таблицы на "значимые" и остальные. Для каждого значимого поля создать собственную таблицу истории (кто, когда и на что изменил значение), а для остальных полей создать одну таблицу, куда записывать изменения, при каждом событии изменения хотя бы одного из полей входящих  в категорию "остальные".

Второй подход вообще позволяет удалить "значимые" поля из таблицы **А**, а просто брать последнюю запись из соответствующей таблицы истории. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

**UPDATE**

**БД - MSSQL**

Comment: Может вам поможет [бинарный журнал](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/binary-log.html)?

Comment: Используется MSSQL

Comment: Можно писать логи в таблицу : поле=значение.
Вопрос в том, как вам нужно просматривать логи?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно создать таблицу с примерно следующей структурой, заполнением которой будет заниматься триггер. При этом не важно, в какой таблице изменились данные -- т.е. можно безболезненно расширяться.

```
Колонки: id (PK), таблица*, колонка*, предыдущее значение, результирующее значение, дата/время, пользователь.

* Таблица, в которой произошло изменение;
** Колонка в этой таблице.
```

Comment: Тогда пару вопросов:
1) Что писать в столбцы "таблица", "колонка"? ID из системных таблиц?
2) Какого типа будут поля "предыдущее значение", "результируещее значение"?

Comment: 1) В столбец "Таблица" -- имя таблицы, "Колонка" -- колонка той таблицы. Не ID, а их наименование. *Например*, у вас есть таблицы `clients` и `orders`; в `clients` колонки `id`, `firstname`, `middlename`, `lastname`, `birthday`, в `orders` -- `id`, `number`, `client`, `description`. Вам нужно отслеживать изменение `clients.birthday`. В триггере на INSERT/UPDATE будете сохранять в системную таблицу истории изменения реквизитов, например, `sys_diary`, записи, где "таблица" будет "clients", а колонка -- "birthday".

2) Для хранения истории нет необходимости в преобразовании, так что -- текст.

Comment: А почему бы не использовать идентификаторы таблиц и столбцов из системных таблиц?

Comment: @Данил, можно и ID -- что удобнее.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно подойдет [это](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: К сожалению располагаем версией Standart

Answer (score 1):

А сущность значений в чем заключается? Работаю с системой интернет агазина, там записываются логи изменения состояния заказа, цены и артикула- остальное не пишется так как не является существенным в принципе.

Comment: Но однажды может понадобится узнать кто и когда изменил какое-то другое значение, не "занчимое"